# Why doesn't the word boundary \b match whitespace?

Tags: javascript, regex

I don't understand why I'm getting the following output from the JavaScript console. To my understanding, `\b` is supposed to match whitespace characters as well?

```
> r = /\brecurring\b/ig
/\brecurring\b/gi

> r.test('RECURRING')
true

> r.test('XXX RECURRING')
false
```

Comment: Remove the global flag `/g`. Note that `\b` is an anchor that by itself does not match a character.

Comment: `\b` does not match whitespace. It matches a location between a non-word and a word char in this pattern. But the problem is not the pattern anyway, just the `g` flag with the `RegExp#test` method.

Comment: Why is the `g` a problem?

Comment: That's just how JS was designed 20-ish years ago.